# Subsets of $[n]$ of size $k$ with exactly one couple of consecutive integers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I hope I'm not asking a question that has previously been asked (and answered).

I have to determine how many subsets of $[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$ of size $k$ contain exactly one couple $(i,i+1)$ of subsequent integers.
I have used the following approach: let $T=(t_1,\dots,t_n)\subset\{0,1\}^n$ be a binary string of length $n$, identifying a subset of size $k$ drawn from $[n]$, i.e. $\sum_i t_i=k$. For $T$ to meet the conditions stated above, it must be the case that $T$ contains $k-2$ non consecutive ones and a couple of consecutive ones.

To build such sequence, I used the method of stars and bars: first find a sequence of length $k-1$ with no consecutive numbers and then obtain a sequence of length $k$ with one consecutive couple.

1. Place $n-k$ consecutive zeros in a string.
2. There are $n-k+1$ places where $k-1$ ones can be placed so that they are non consecutive, hence there are $\binom{n-k+1}{k-1}$ sequences of length $n-1$ with $k-1$ ones that are non consecutive.
3. Add an extra one close to the previous one. For any sequence in $(2.)$ there are $(k-1)$ possibilities.

Overall, that would give $(k-1)\times\binom{n-k+1}{k-1}$ possibilities.

Does this make sense? Thanks!

Comment: I think it should be $(k-1)\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}$

Comment: It does not work, because when you re-insert back an element, nothing grants that the situation in which you take $3$ consecutive elements is avoided.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, the $n-k+1$ places for the *ones* are the places (bars) between two *zeros* plus at the ends: so the process seems ok and $3$ consecutive elements should not happen, or there is a bug I do not see ?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I see the process as $$00000\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \_^{\left( {} \right)} 0^1 0^1 0^{\left( {} \right)} 0^{\left( 1 \right)} 0^{\left( {} \right)} \quad  \Rightarrow \quad \_^{\left( {} \right)} 0^1 0^{11} 0^{\left( {} \right)} 0^{\left( 1 \right)} 0^{\left( {} \right)} 
$$

Comment: @GCab: yes, I really understood your algorithm too late. You are right, my bad.

Comment: Just a terminology fix: it is best to replace *close* with *to the right of one previously placed $1$*. Then it is clear that the answer is $(k-1)$ times a binomial coefficient provided by stars and bars.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, yes in fact *close* is misleading, and should be better specified as you said.

Answer (score 2):

By way of enrichment here is a solution using generating functions.
We start by selecting the first value:

$$\frac{z}{1-z}.$$

Then  we add  in $k-1$  gaps, marking  gaps of  size  one (consecutive
values):

$$\left(uz+\frac{z^2}{1-z}\right)^{k-1}.$$

Finally we sum all contributions (subsets) that terminate in at most $n$:

$$[z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} \times \cdot.$$ We get the answer

$$[z^n] [u^1] \frac{z}{1-z}
\left(uz+\frac{z^2}{1-z}\right)^{k-1}
\frac{1}{1-z}.$$

The coefficient extractor in $u$ ensures that we have exactly one pair
of consecutive items. We get

$$[z^n] \frac{z}{1-z}
\times z  {k-1\choose 1} 
\left(\frac{z^2}{1-z}\right)^{k-2}
\times \frac{1}{1-z}.$$

This is

$$(k-1) [z^n] \frac{z^{1+1+2k-4}}{(1-z)^k}
= (k-1) [z^n] \frac{z^{2k-2}}{(1-z)^k}
= (k-1) [z^{n-2k+2}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^k}
\\ = (k-1) {n-2k+2+k-1\choose k-1}
= (k-1) {n-k+1\choose k-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It may be of interest to consider an additional method for solving this type of problems.

[image: Seq_2_adj]

As shown in the sketch, consider a subset $\left\{ {a_{\,1} ,\,a_{\,2} ,\,\; \cdots \,,a_{\,k}  = h} \right\}$  with the given requisites, 
and whose last element equals $h$.
Let's take the backward delta $\left[ {a_{\,1}  - 0,\,a_{\,2}  - a_{\,1} ,\,\; \cdots \,,a_{\,k}  - a_{\,k - 1} } \right]$
which will have all positive elements, of which (apart eventually the 1st element) only one will have value $=1$
and the others shall be greater than that, alltogether summing to $h$.
Let's eliminate the element with Delta $=1$, we are left with $k-1$ element, the 1st with min. value $1$ and the remaining with min. value $2$.
Let's deduct such a minimum threshold, and we arrive to get
a *weak composition* of $h-2k$ into $k-1$ parts, with $4 \leqslant  2k \leqslant h$.
Their total number is known to be
$$
\left( \begin{gathered}
  \left( {h - 2k} \right) + \left( {k - 1} \right) - 1 \\ 
  \left( {k - 1} \right) - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) = \left( \begin{gathered}
  h - k - 2 \\ 
  k - 2 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\quad \left| \begin{gathered}
  \,2 \leqslant k \hfill \\
  \;2k \leqslant h \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
Multiplying by the number of possible positions of the eliminated element, and summing over $h$ we get
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \left( {k - 1} \right)\sum\limits_{2k\, \leqslant \,h\, \leqslant \,n} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  h - k - 2 \\ 
  k - 2 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}  = \left( {k - 1} \right)\left( {\left( \begin{gathered}
  n + 1 - k - 2 \\ 
  k - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) - \left( \begin{gathered}
  2k - k - 2 \\ 
  k - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \left( {k - 1} \right)\left( {\left( \begin{gathered}
  n - k - 1 \\ 
  k - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) - \left( \begin{gathered}
  k - 2 \\ 
  k - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} \right)\quad \left| \begin{gathered}
  \,2 \leqslant k \hfill \\
  \;2k \leqslant n \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. = \left( {k - 1} \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  n - k - 1 \\ 
  k - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$